# firefox - unable to receive event for dynamic javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dynamic

I have some dynamic javascript that creates elements, with a click event element handler... the script is included from another domain.

However with Firefox at runtime it gives a security warning and does not process the click event (Chrome works fine).

A simplified version below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<h2 id="headertitle">TEST</h2>
<br/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="somewhereelse.com/script.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript include:

```
document.getElementById("headertitle").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin',
            "<button value='TEST' onclick='clickHandler(this)' >Button</button>");

function clickHandler(evt){
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Warning Message:

> Security wrapper denied access to property undefined on privileged
>   Javascript object. Support for exposing privileged objects to
>   untrusted content via **exposedProps** is being gradually removed -
>   use WebIDL bindings or Components.utils.cloneInto instead. Note that
>   only the first denied property access from a given global object will
>   be reported.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code here and it worked fine for me on Firefox 50.1.0. =/

However, I strongly recommend you use JQuery to deal with events triggered by dynamically created elements. JQuery handles the DOM differently, it's cross-browser and it's just made for this kind of situation. It may solve your problem. =D

Try and change your html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<h2 id="headertitle">TEST</h2>
<br/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="somewhereelse.com/script.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and your JS code to

```
document.getElementById("headertitle").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeBegin',
            '<button value="TEST" class="clickable" id="btn1">Button</button>');

$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id') + ' was clicked');
});
```

That should make it work!
Cheers! =)

Comment: import jQuery? just to fix it? R U kidding?

Comment: Well, I doubt he'd be using it only once. AND, if he's working with dynamic html elements, then YES, I strongly recommend he uses JQuery to handle them. JQuery is basically made for live DOM manupulation and cross-browsing.

Plus, it is the easy way around and will get him started, he can evolve by himself from there. I believe people are smart! =)

Futhermore, I'd rather help him get whatever he needs done, than to criticize arrogantly people who are trying to help, without offering any solution for the problem: it seems way too juvenile to do so. =P